# Factorization Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f_1:A \longrightarrow A_1 , f_2 :A \longrightarrow A_2$ homomorphism of rings such that $ker(f_1)\subseteq ker(f_2)$. Prove that exist a homomorphism $f:A_1 \longrightarrow A_2 $ such that $f_2=f \circ f_1$.

Is a generalization of factorization theorem. In the book the hint is that define $f$ as $f(f_1(a))=f_2(a)$. But in that case $f: f_1(A)\subseteq A_1 \longrightarrow A_2$ and the proof that is a homomorphism is not difficult. My question is if you can define a $f$ that goes from $A_1$ to $A_2$. If $f_1$ is a epimorphism is very easy because $f_1(A)=A$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your question is, but I think you're saying that you think the statement (which you appear to be saying is given in your book) is false.

In that case you'd be correct.
Let $f_1 : \Bbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \Bbb{Q}$ be the inclusion and let $f_2 : \Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}$ be the identity map. Then both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are injective, so $\ker f_1 =\ker f_2 = 0$. However, there is no map at all from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $\Bbb{Z}$, let alone one with $f\circ f_1=f_2$.

Note that in this case $f_1$ is actually an epimorphism, since if $g,h : \Bbb{Q}\to R$ are ring homomorphisms that agree when restricted to $\Bbb{Z}$, they must agree everywhere since $$g(n/m)=g(n)/g(m)=h(n)/h(m)=h(n/m).$$

Thus it doesn't suffice for $f_1$ to be an epimorphism. It does however suffice for $f_1$ to be surjective (note that in rings this is a distinct notion).

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109/69100) for more on epimorphisms of rings.

Comment: And if $f_1$ is a epimorphism is true?.

Comment: @JuanDanielValdiviaFuentes I just edited to address that.